# Typescript won't give an error when I'm destructuring a Partial type after destructuring the original type

Tags: javascript, typescript, types, interface

Given this scenario:

```
interface TEST {
  somename: string;
  somenum: number;
}

const partialTest: Partial<TEST> = {
  somename: '',
  somenum: undefined,
}
const test: TEST = {
  somename: '',
  somenum: 1,
}

const destructured: TEST = {
  ...test,
  ...partialTest,
}

console.log(destructured);
```

Why doesn't typescript give me an error saying that `destructured`'s `somenum` property is undefined?

`console.log` effectively shows that `somenum`'s value is undefined.

Comment: Do you use `--strictNullChecks`? Without it, just about any type is `| undefined`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder hi tj, yes. `const myvar: number = undefined;` gives an error as it should.

Comment: IIRC Typescript does not distinguish between "undefined" and "non-existant" which is indeed a problem here

Comment: @JonasWilms Quite the problem indeed. Do you know if this is one of those problems that the typescript team currently doesn't have a solution for?

Comment: @CodeIntern just found a discussion on it, they would've to add another "not-defined" type, and that would cause a lot of work for a minor improvement

Answer (score 2):

It's interesting. If you let typescript infer the types, it works correctly:

```
const partialTest = {
  somename: '',
  somenum: undefined
};

const destructured: TEST = { // error
  ...test,
  ...partialTest, 
};
```

That is because on spreading `undefined` over `string` will result in `undefined` which doesn't fit to TEST, while spreading `string | undefined` over `string` results in `string`, which fits to TEST.

Unless there is no `missing` type to distinguish between `undefined` and "not-defined", this [wont fix](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/16509)